# CSS Grid box shadow not following the flow of the grid near the bottom of the container

Tags: html, css

Hello there so I have an app here that I want to polish.  This little thing is driving me nuts, the container displays a grid system of pictures in a box, the box has box shadow and all is well, but near the end of the container it levels out as opposed to staying with the flow.

Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXRfK.jpg

```
.memePost {
    padding: 10px;
     border: 1px solid #DDD;
    border-collapse: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

Comment: Put up a working snippet illustrating the issue for a better chance of getting help.

Comment: It's hard to say with this info. But I would try adding padding to the bottom of the container housing each `.memePost` and I would also try to set that container's overflow to `visible` if it isn't already.